# Can not show data from the script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I use the below command in oracle sql developer , it works fine to output data

```
SQL> SELECT table1.documentid  FROM table1

documentid
==========
001
002
003
```

While when use the below script

```
 SELECT table1.documentid  FROM table1
 join table2 
 on table2.id=table1.documentid ;
```

the output is

```
documentid
==========
no rows select
```

I am wonder why no data will be output , what will be the possible reason of my error ?

really thanks for help

Comment: Did you commit all outstanding transactions after inserting your data? If not, the data (or changes to data) will only be visible to the session that performed the change on the database: other sessions will not see the changes. If you don't commit before closing the session, open transactions are usually rolled back.

Comment: thanks your reply ,

sorry to not understanding what I need to do to commit it ?

Comment: I am wonder if it is because not commit the data , why the above first command can output data ? thanks

Comment: Show your table2 data 's, in table2 got id with 001,002,003 ? and what datatype ? is it integer or varchar ? if integer how u can store 001 ?

Comment: both are char .

Answer (score 0):

As this is join of two tables, query will return result if there are matching values between `table2.id` and `table1.documentid`.

You said that `table1.documentid` contains values 001, 002 and 003 - it means that `table2.id` should contain *at least* one of these values  - otherwise, query won't return anything.

As it turns out that it really didn't return any rows, it means that `table2` is either empty or doesn't contain 001, 002 nor 003 in its `id` column.

---

This is what you currently have:

```
SQL> select * from table1;

DOC
---
001
002
003

SQL> select * from table2;

no rows selected

SQL> SELECT table1.documentid  FROM table1
  2  join table2
  3  on table2.id=table1.documentid ;

no rows selected
```

You *could* get the result if you switch to **outer join**:

```
SQL> SELECT table1.documentid  FROM table1
  2  left join table2
  3  on table2.id=table1.documentid ;

DOC
---
001
003
002

SQL>
```